# what's the meaning of apiVersion of batch/v1beta1

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm confused with the following response.

what's the meaning of `"apiVersion": "v1",`???

I'm expecting the `apiVersion` to be `v1beta1`.

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/apis/batch/v1beta1
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "batch/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "cronjobs",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "CronJob",
      "verbs": [
        "create",
        "delete",
        "deletecollection",
        "get",
        "list",
        "patch",
        "update",
        "watch"
      ],
      "shortNames": [
        "cj"
      ],
      "categories": [
        "all"
      ],
      "storageVersionHash": "h/JlFAZkyyY="
    },
    {
      "name": "cronjobs/status",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "CronJob",
      "verbs": [
        "get",
        "patch",
        "update"
      ]
    }
  ]
}controlplane $
```

Answer (score 1):

Modular structure of K8s API, which allows for versioning and grouping.
You can find more information about on the following pages:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/api-machinery/api-group.md
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-groups
- https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/api-machinery/api-group.md
- https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-apiversion-definition-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused by the output format. The actual output is `metav1.APIResourceList`:

```golang
// APIResourceList is a list of APIResource, it is used to expose the name of the
// resources supported in a specific group and version, and if the resource
// is namespaced.
type APIResourceList struct {
    TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
    // groupVersion is the group and version this APIResourceList is for.
    GroupVersion string `json:"groupVersion" protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=groupVersion"`
    // resources contains the name of the resources and if they are namespaced.
    APIResources []APIResource `json:"resources" protobuf:"bytes,2,rep,name=resources"`
}
```

In the example:

```json
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
```

is `APIResourceList.TypeMeta`, it says kind `APIResourceList` belongs to version `v1`. The latter part i.e.:

```json
  "groupVersion": "batch/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
...
```

says that corresponding resources belong to groupVersion `batch/v1beta1`.

Hope it is clearer now.